# Check if array / 2d array / array of structs / array of strings was freed

Tags: c, free

Is there any way to  check if array was fully freed and nothing was left behind? Valgrind only says that there are some unfreed blocks. Is debugger or something like that made just for this?

Comment: What do you mean? A 2D array requires a single `free`, the same for a `struct { ... } x[]`. The rest is already told you by Valgrind. You actually should know where/which allocated block you `free`d. And a debugger is made for - well - debugging...

Comment: @Olaf is there a Windows version of `Valgrind`, I just ask?

Comment: @user3706129 You mean a pointer ...?

Comment: There is no way to check if a Pointer was `free`ed in `C`, only if you use a Memory check tool like `Valgrind`, but you should take care your self for doing that and also setting the pointer to NULL [Like this](http://ideone.com/5W8tjN) or [Like this](http://ideone.com/UF4ubQ).

Comment: @Michi: How should I know. Happily avoided to work for/under Windows since 28 years - mostly. But OP mentiones Valgrind, so I assume he uses it.

Comment: You do not `free` a pointer either. You `free` the object it points to. But only of that was allocated before.

Comment: @Olaf Nice replay :)). Any way I'm not against Microsoft or something but i just hate every thing with what they come out. It happens sometimes that I gave an Answer and  had to check it if apply's for Windows too.

Comment: You just have to be careful: if you `free` an array of `struct`, whose elements contained pointers to allocated memory within any `struct`, it's too late, and the nested pointers' memory will not get `free`d. Just adopt good housekeeping practices, in this case `free` your memory in the reverse order it was allocated. And as @Michi advised, set an unallocated pointer to `NULL` because even if you don't explicitly check that, `free` is tolerant of being  passed a `NULL` pointer, but not a de-allocated pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, no, there is no way to know if you have freed everything just by looking at the pointers. You must know your data structure and algorithm and know when to release alocated memory.

Under Windows (MSC) I use the following to check at the end, when the program terminates, if I have freed all allocated memory:

```
// Check heap upon exit: all memory freed and not corrupted?
#include <crtdbg.h>
_CrtMemState memStateStart, memStateEnd, memStateDelta;

int WinMain(...
{
    ...
    // Make a checkpoint of the heap's state so we can later check the heap is still OK
   _CrtMemCheckpoint( &memStateStart );

   ghMainWnd = CreateWindow(                           // Create the app. main window
           ...
   );
   ...
}
...
WndProc(hWnd, msg,...)
{
    ...
            case WM_CLOSE:
                    // Check the heap
                    _CrtMemCheckpoint( &memStateEnd );
                    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN,   _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
                    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR,  _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
                    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
                    if (_CrtMemDifference( &memStateDelta, &memStateStart, &memStateEnd ))
                        _CrtMemDumpStatistics( &memStateDelta );
                    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
                    DestroyWindow (hWnd);
                    return (0);
```